# Alternative graphic when a question has been answered

Tags: feature-request, answers

I find the yellow text in the green box of a question that has been answered difficult to read. I wouldn't necessarily like to see this changed, but I think an addition to the box to make it more obvious the question was answered would be a definite improvement.

Would it be possible to add at a stylish ribbon through the top-left corner of the box with the Stack Overflow checkmark on it.

Here's roughly my suggestion. (I just threw these together in a few minutes; It can be done much better, I'm sure.)

[image][image]

Comment: Not that I don't like the graphic, but I hope we don't end up with web 2.0 graphics

Comment: I am not an expert at all, but adding a true image (with the proper alt-text) might be nice for the visually impaired as well? And as an aside: on (for example?) http://superuser.com/, there's no box at all, unless a question has been answered.

Comment: Looks like a Nike sweatband.  Can't you Nike guys just [sponsor-a-tag] like normal people?  I hate viral advertising.  Viral advertiser.  Nyah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My simple suggestion would be to make the box more green and the text off-white.

Comment: On low monitor brightness settings, I can hardly tell the difference between the regular box and the "answered" box. Even at regular brightness, it still is too similar to the others.