# Accepted answer box colour discernibility

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta, design, homepage

Compare the pair:

[image]

At least on my laptop, the two boxes (on MSO) are very similar in colour, and not immediately noticeable that one has already been answered, unlike on other sites such as the main SO site, where the yellowish colour is immediately apparent.

[image]

Could this be changed?  Thanks.

EDIT: note that this is only for the front page, not the questions page, nor the "unanswered" page.

Comment: The difference in colour is restricted to the active tab only.

Comment: @AsheeshR: for me it appears on all tabs on the front page, but other pages aren't affected.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74314/alternative-graphic-when-a-question-has-been-answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are absolutely correct, the RGB values for the 2 boxes are different (the font is also quite different, but that's probably a different issue).

Here's a blown up specimen with hex colors:

[image]

I understand the whole meta philosophy of being muted/grayscale/less-in-your-face, but I see no reason why they should be different and propose that the one on the right (since it is more prominent) be made consistent across all applicable pages.

Comment: The Meta background is darker and less saturated; that fits in well with the greyscale theme. But I don't see why we can't keep that and just change the text color to a brighter yellow.

Answer (score 0):

On my screen, the MSO box looks like the SO box you posted.  Maybe you need to adjust your monitor?

Comment: Mine's looking like qantas's, and that from two different screens, so I'm pretty sure that's not the problem

Comment: No, this is wrong.

Comment: Now that he posted an update and specified what he was talking about, I see the difference.